# Enumerating directed cacti by the number of vertices and edges

Tags: enumerative-combinatorics, directed-graphs

Let's say that a **directed cactus** is a labeled directed graph, such that each vertex belongs to at most one simple cycle. In other words, it is a directed graph such that all its strongly connected components are simple cycles or isolated vertices.

It is possible to show that the total number of directed cacti on $n$ vertices is exactly $2^{\binom{n}{2}} n!$. The proof is below:

> This is because for each of ${{n \choose 2} \choose m}$ sets of non-cycle edges, there are exactly $n!$ ways to pick their orientation and add some cycles (to create strongly connected components), so that one gets a directed cactus. 
>  It is true for $m=0$, because there are no non-cycle edges, and there are $n!$ ways to connect some of the vertices into cycles (corresponding to cycle presentation of a permutation). Now let's say we showed that there are $n!$ ways for some graph $G$, and we add an edge $(u,v)$ to the graph. 
>  - If $u$ and $v$ belong to different comparable cycles, we direct the $(u, v)$ edge in a single possible way; 
>  - If $u$ and $v$ belong to different incomparable cycles, we direct the $(u, v)$ edge from smaller vertex to larger; 
>  - If $u$ and $v$ belong to the same cycle, we apply the swap $(u v)$ to the permutation represented by the strongly connected components as cycles, and orient the $(u, v)$ edge from larger vertex to smaller; 
>  This procedure is revertible, hence there will be the same amount of ways to pick orientation and assign cycles for all possible undirected graphs of non-cycle edges.

Unfortunately, it seems to be very difficult to find any simple formula for the number of directed cacti that have $n$ vertices *and* $m$ edges, due to the fact that isolated vertices do not produce any edges (while any cycle on $k > 1$ vertices produces $k$ edges). Is there any way to account for it?